How can I recover files from an emptied trash can on a MacBook M1?
On the 23rd of August 2024, all the files on my MacBook Pro 2022 M1's desktop were moved to the trash can and then deleted. The folders contained two years' worth of my work and personal documents. My life is now in shambles.
I've already discovered the following:

No copies can be retrieved from iCloud, and third-party apps like Disk Drill or Tenorshare are unable to do so as well.
A recovery firm has informed me that it's impossible to recover files from an M1 with SSD disks involved.

Question: Is there truly no company or tech person in the world who can recover these files? I'm not a millionaire, but I'm willing to go to great lengths to retrieve my files. Please advise me.

Well, the experts are right on this: it‘s practically impossible to recover deleted files from an SSD.

How long did you continue to use that Mac after deleting the files?

These files were not being backed up?

Were the files not in iCloud? You should be able to recover deleted files for 30 days from iCloud. This really shows why it's so important to have another copy of your data on a separate device. Otherwise, they are very fragile.

Unfortunately, with M1 Macs and SSDs, recovery is a whole new level of difficult because of the way the data is stored and encrypted. Unlike traditional hard drives, SSDs start overwriting deleted data almost immediately, making recovery next to impossible once it’s been deleted.
Most data recovery companies won’t be able to help because the M1 chip’s security features make it tough. Some forensic-level services might have a shot, but those are super expensive and even then, success isn’t guaranteed. I know it’s not what you want to hear, but it sounds like you’ve already tried the main options out there.
If you haven’t yet, maybe double-check with Apple directly or consult with a specialized Mac forensic expert—sometimes, they might know of new techniques or tools. It’s a long shot, but at this point, anything is worth a try. I really hope you find a way!

Thank you so much for your prompt reply, Lostmarien. A harsh new reality starts today for me. I will keep an eye out for anybody who can make recommendations on experts up for the task. Anybody? Again, thank you so much!
